# Mouse shortcuts for Visual Studio (F5, F10, F11)

Tags: mouse, visual-studio, mouse-click, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to configure the mouse shortcut buttons to simulate F5, F10, F11 keys inside Visual Studio?

Basically to allow debugging an application in Visual Studio with just the mouse.

I don't have a mouse like and the answer to this might decide if I purchase one or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt about Visual Studio, but I suggest checking your mouse application/drivers for these settings for these mappings, or AutoHotkey if you want to map standard buttons L/M/R/Fwd/Back (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AHK above, I would recommend also StrokesPlus.
(in my AHK Alt+LClick selects (*<+LButton::*) the whole text in input-editBox and copies it into clipboard,
Shift+Alt+LClick selects the whole text in input-editBox and cuts it into clipboard
don't foreget about AHK-"pre-header" #IfWinActive C:\path_to_msvs\devenv.exe)

My personal mouse-gestures of StrokesPlus in the MSVC IDE (stroke:action):

- stright line forward: Run (F5 of MSVS) ( *acSendKeys("{F_8}"*) in terms of StrokesPlus)
- stright line back: Alt+arrow left (go back as history of browser)
- stright line up: Enter key ( *acSendKeys("{ENTER}"*) in terms of StrokesPlus)

... like line down - toggle breakpoint, and so on so on.
So just assign keys like F10, F11 etc to gestures in StrokesPlus.

A couple pictures from internet -

[image]
not ads
[image]